# Ajax, AccessControl и уничтожение сессии

Tags: yii2

Возникла такая проблема. Есть контроллер доступ к которому осуществляется через AccessControl

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'state'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

**actionLogin**, **actionLogout** и **actionIndex** возвращают обычные view c HTML кодом. Но также есть **actionState** который дёргается через AJAX cо страницы **actionIndex** и возвращает JSON.

```
[
    'status' => true,
    'data' => [
        //...
    ],
]
```

Время жизни сессии допустим 5 минут. Если пользователь успешно залогинился и его перенаправило на **actionIndex**, на которой есть кнопка для отправки запроса на **actionState**. Но если пользователь пойдёт попить чайку допустим то сессия успеет умереть (**Или сессию убили на стороне сервера**). И при запросе к **actionState** пользователя перенаправит на **actionLogin** и в ответе вместо JSON , будет HTML страницы login

Хотелось бы в случае разлогинивания пользователя отвечать на ajax в формате, и чтоб при наличии ключа **redirect**, **frontend** редиректил пользователя на страницу логина

```
[
    'status' => false,
    'redirect' => '/login',
    'data' => [
        //...
    ],
]
```

Как перехватить редирект и сформировать вместо него JSON Response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насколько правильное решение. Но решил так.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index', 'state'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function () {
                if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                    \Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 302;
                    \Yii::$app->response->data = [
                        'status' => false,
                        'redirect' => Url::to(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl),
                    ];
                } else {
                    $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
                }
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```